# How to auto-start my bash_profile?

Tags: administration

When I open a new terminal, it doesn't execute auto-start my bash_profile. I need to do "source .bash_profile".

When I use Screen, it happens again.

Comment: Scroll down to **INVOCATION** in `man bash` for information on what files are sourced when.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but close enough: new terminals and terminals spawned by screen are not login shells. See the linked answer for further details.

Comment: Please give more details about how are you opening a terminal...

Comment: 1. Right click the terminal icon on Ubuntu.

Comment: 2. username@hostname:~$ screen

Comment: 1. and 2. both need to use "source .bash_profile" to reload

Answer (score 3):

The file ~/.bash_profile is loaded only when you invoke bash as a login shell, otherwise load the ~/.bashrc

I mean if you open a terminal in X Window likely is invoked as a non-login shell. Many X terminal emulators have an option to configure as a login shell every time you open either a window or a tab.